# Where to put test implementation classes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have a class in `lib` that has some application logic in it. I want to have a separate implementation of this class that will be used in automated functional tests. Is there a good place where I can put this class to? Ideally I don't want it to be loaded when I am running a web site in production.

Answer (score 1):

if the class in `lib` holds application logic, it should go in `app/xyz`.

if you want to create a dummy subclass or a ducktype for testing, just put it into your test-file.